# Migrate MongoDB arbiter

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have a mongodb replica set (which is part of a shard) where I want to migrate the arbiter to a new host. I didn't found any instructions for this case, so I'm not sure how to do this.

My current approach would be to start an arbiter on the new host, add him to the replica set, and then remove the old one.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Try it and if it doesn't work out, come back :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact it is much simpler:

1. Start the new arbiter
2. Connect to the primary member
3. Execute

   ```
   cfg = rs.conf()
   cfg.members[0].host = newhost
   rs.reconfig(cfg)
   ```
4. Now you can shut down the old arbiter

Don't forget to change your options (--replSet) in `/etc/sysconfig/mongod`, if set.

Reference: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Adding+an+Arbiter

Answer (score 1):

There is a command much more easier:

```
rs.addArb("[hostname]:[port]")
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replication-architectures/#replica-set-arbiter-nodes